# R: Connect 2D coordinates with lines in 3D plot and add a normal distribution pdf based on the coordinates

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl

Similar to [3D Plot of normal distribution in R around a (x,y) point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125313/3d-plot-of-normal-distribution-in-r-around-a-x-y-point/36126042#36126042) using code like

```
library(rgl)
open3d()

x <- seq(0, 10, length=100)
y <- seq(0, 10, length=100)


z = outer(x,y, function(x,y) dnorm(x,2.5,1)*dnorm(y,2.5,1))

persp3d(x, y, z,col = rainbow(100))
```

I want to draw a normal distribution onto a (x,y) diagram. However, differently to the first question, I want to draw this normal distribution along some specific coordinates (they have all z=0 and "lie on the ground" of (x,y)). They mimic the walk of a person and have coordinates

```
g=matrix(c(0,0,3,1,4,2,5,3,6,4,5,5,4,6,6,6,8,5,9,6)
  ,nrow=10,ncol=2,byrow= TRUE)
```

So my questions are:
(1)How can I add this 2D data to the 3D plot and connect all points through a line such that it depicts the walk? It should lie on the ground.
(2) How can I draw a normal distribution around the "walk"? This should be 3D.

Thanks a lot

Update: The idea is to assign probabilities in a next exercise to the walk of a second person, too, and then compute the probability they met somewhere.

Update2: I was maybe not very clear what I want, so I try my best to be more precise. The walk, as depicted by the coordinates in g, is just a rough line. It should be displayed on the ground. The real task I am interested in is as follows: it is possible that the person is not exactly walking on the line. The probability, however, at any point is given by a Normal function (the PDF) of its shortest distance to the line. So I want to draw a normal PDF multiple (probably infinite times) around the line. The final 3D plot will probably look like some mountains. This is related to my earlier question where I asked how to draw a normal PDF multiple times such that its 3D plot looks like a vulcano.

Update3: The answer below does not show the result to Update2 but it clearly provides guidance for a part of the original question. Thus, I mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. (Note that I made the rainbow surface transparent).

```
library(rgl)
open3d()

x <- seq(0, 10, length=100)
y <- seq(0, 10, length=100)

z = outer(x,y, function(x,y) dnorm(x,2.5,1)*dnorm(y,2.5,1))

persp3d(x, y, z,col = rainbow(100),alpha=0.5)

# now draw the line 
#    note:
#    -  the "add=T" parameter that appends it to the previous 3d-plot

g=matrix(c(0,0,3,1,4,2,5,3,6,4,5,5,4,6,6,6,8,5,9,6)
         ,nrow=10,ncol=2,byrow= TRUE)

lines3d(g[,1],g[,2],0,color="purple",add=T)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is already quite close, but how could I add that the normal pdf is drawn along the line? As I wrote at the beginning, this is related to another recent post of me. Would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: So you want the height to be zero (like you said "on the ground") - or do you want the height to be the pdf value, so it is on the surface?

Comment: I apologize if I was not very precise. I want "both" :-) Having said that, the line depicts the walk and should be on the ground. Second, there is some uncertainty regarding the walk/coordinates, which indicated by the normal PDF that should not just be on a single point but follow the walk/line. Please let me also update the text above.

Comment: It seems you want to calculate a new pdf at every point (i.e. the probability distribution of where the random walker will be a few steps later), and then somehow display all those pdfs at once. While one could do that, the calculation is expensive and a bit complicated, and the display would probably not be comprehensible. Displaying multiple transparent surfaces (as opposed to only one) require a raytracing approach.

Comment: The original question was clear, and I answered it clearly. I would suggest you mark this one correct and ask another question with your more complex request.